# Error when importing attachment from Gmail to Google Site

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to move my big mails from Gmail to a Google Site with a Google Apps Script. The script runs without problem but when the attachment size exeeds 10Mo an error occured :

**"Server error, please try again later..."**

```
var att = ms[m].getAttachments();
for (var a=0; a<att.length; a++){
tab[3][m][5][a] = att[a].copyBlob();
    ...
}
...
var atttach = post.addHostedAttachment(tab[3][i][5][b]);
...
```

Comment: Yes, there are limits on Google Site file attachment size (http://support.google.com/sites/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96770) but I don't think that you are getting error because of file size. Let us wait for someone from Google to answer your question.

Comment: @Ahmad
Thanks for the link, I see that my file size is under the limit, but I'm sure that I'm getting the error because of file size, I tried with different files (video, archive...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that their is a blob size limit in Apps Script as 10 MB. Probably that is causing the error.
Check the discussion in Issue Tracker where Evin Levey says

> We some some strict internal limits that we're working on raising...
>   It should now be at 5MB, with 10MB coming shortly.

http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=552